# Connection to database fails using layershift and MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb

I'm using layershift for the deployment of a .war-file (program written in Java using eclipse-19), but the connection to the database doesn't work. So I'm trying to run the program locally and connect to the database lying on the layershift server (using a local database works out without problems).

I have added the connector mariadb-java-client-3.1.4.jar to the projects classpath as well as the tomcat/lib.

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
```

While configuring the layershift server I choose the MariaDB version I used when I ran the program locally, 10.4.28.

```
public String URLAbrufen() {

    //String server = "mysql://localhost";
    String server = "mariadb://node495323-studiquizv3.j.layershift.co.uk";
    String port = "3306";
    String database = "studiquiz";      
    String URL = "jdbc:" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database;
    System.out.println(URL);

    return URL;         
}
```

creates this URL:
*jdbc:mariadb://node495323-studiquizv3.j.layershift.co.uk:3306/studiquiz*

With which I try to connect the database like this:

*Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, BenutzerDB, PasswortDB);*

using the credentials provided by layershift while setting up the server.

If I run the programm, the following exception is thrown:
*java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=node495323-studiquizv3.j.layershift.co.uk)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection timed out: no further information*

The connection to the database on the layershift server doesn't seem to work, how can I establish this connection successfully?

Minimal reproducible example of my code:

```
package studiquiz_test_p1;

import java.sql.*;

public class main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
            
            String server = "mariadb://node495323-studiquizv3.j.layershift.co.uk";
            String port = "3306";
            String database = "studiquiz";      
            String URL = "jdbc:" + server + ":" + port + "/" + database;
            
            String BenutzerDB = "root";
            String PasswortDB = "password"; 
            
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, BenutzerDB, PasswortDB);            
            //Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            
            System.out.println("Connection successful.");       
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed [ClassNotFoundException].");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed [SQLException].");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Thank you for your instruction to improve the quality of my question. I edited the question trying to fullfil the aspects you mentioned.

Comment: Is this the error message you get when you try to connect to the MariaDB server from your local host or do you get this message when you deploy your application on the layershift host? Usually the database provider does not give access to external IPs to their database, that would be a security risk. That's why you can't even reach the host from "locally".

Comment: The console in eclipse shows this error:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=node495323-studiquizv3.j.layershift.co.uk)(port=3306)(type=primary). Connection timed out: no further information
when I run program locally, which begins with the initialization of the database (Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"); and creation of the tables and entries needed from beginning).
When I deploy the .war-file, the deployment process seems to work and I can open the website, but inputs needing the database for checking don't work.

Comment: When I run the program after deploying, I don't have any console to get debugging or logging information. I have tried to use Log4j but couldn't bring it to work.

If the database provider doesn't give access to external IPs, I understand that running the program locally doesn't let it connect to the database. But then it should work for the version I deployed on the layershift server, shouldn't it?

Comment: When it doesn't work on the layershift servers as well, you have to check the error messages to see the issue. It might be a different problem, which we don't see. You have to figure out how to get logging to work and/or how to get any error/exception messages. Depending on your setup, the error/exception messages might get logged in a general error file of the server (assuming your don't catch the exceptions yourself). Or you use any logging frameworks which are available to java like slf4j+logback or log4j as you already mentioned.